# run flask app as current user instead of root via supervisor

Tags: flask, gstreamer, video-capture, supervisord

I'm using supervisor to invoke and keep the flask server running to control my web interface was built as a simple video recorder.

Supervisor invokes the server with root privileges so the final recorded files would be unaccessible for the current user since he needs to convert and transfer them to somewhere else at the end.

Is there any solution to tell the supervisor to run flask app as normal user instead of root?

another problem is about live preview which I implemented for my interface. using this option, user can see a live preview for 5 seconds before starting the recording (it's a simple gstreamer pipeline: **gst-launch v4l2src device=/dev/video1 ! jpegdec ! ffmpegcolorspace** )

but after rebooting the system when I try to see this preview it fails and gives me this error in log file:

*ERROR: from element /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstXImageSink:ximagesink0: Could not initialise X output
Additional debug info:
ximagesink.c(1284): gst_ximagesink_xcontext_get (): /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstXImageSink:ximagesink0:
Could not open display
./testWebcam.sh: 5: kill: No such process*

Here is my config file for supervisor placed in `/etc/supervisor/conf.d/RunFlask.conf`:

```
[program:flask_app]                                                                     
command = python main.py                                      
directory = /dir/to/your/app                            
autostart =     true                                                                
autorestart = true
```

and for the sake of being complete, here is the gstreamer pipeline I use to record:

```
nohup gst-launch-1.0 v4l2src do-timestamp=true device=/dev/video0  ! 'video/x-raw,format=BGR,width=1024,height=768'  ! videoconvert ! queue ! x264enc ! mux.  pulsesrc device="alsa_input.usb-Samson_Technologies_Samson_Go_Mic_Direct-00-Direct.analog-stereo" !  'audio/x-raw,rate=88200,channels=1,depth=24' !  audioconvert  !  avenc_aac compliance=experimental ! mux. matroskamux name="mux"  ! filesink location=/home/sina/Desktop/Recordings/Screen.mp4  v4l2src device=/dev/video1 ! videorate  ! 'image/jpeg,framerate=30/1,width=1920,height=1080' ! queue ! mux2. pulsesrc device="alsa_input.usb-046d_Logitech_Webcam_C930e_AAF8A63E-02-C930e.analog-stereo" ! 'audio/x-raw,rate=44100,channels=1,depth=24' !  audioconvert !  avenc_aac compliance=experimental ! queue ! mux2.  matroskamux name="mux2" !   filesink location=/home/sina/Desktop/Recordings/Webcam.mkv &
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify an user in your supervisor config:

```
[program:flask_app]
user=yourusername
```

This will run your flask app under the given user.